# Send responseon EventSubscriber Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to set a response on an eventsubscriber that checks if an API  authorization token it's correct

```
class TokenSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        if ($controller[0] instanceof TokenAuthenticatedController) {
            

            $apiKey = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:ApiKey')->findOneBy(['enabled' => true, 'name' => 'apikey'])->getApiKey();
            $token = $event->getRequest()->headers->get('x-auth-token');
            if ($token !== $apiKey) {
                //send response
            }
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => 'onKernelController',
        ];
    }
}
```

But I cant stop the current request and return a respone as a controller, what is the correct way to send a response with an error message and stop the current request

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that using the `FilterControllerEvent` Event. On that moment, symfony already decided which controller to execute.  I think you might want to look into the Symfony Security component. It can protect routes like what you want, but in a slightly different way (access_control and/or annotations).

If you want to block access to an API (eg. JSON), you easily follow [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/api_key_authentication.html). You can also mix it using the Security annotations on your controllers or actions using [this doc](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/security.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can throw an error here

```
throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Your message here!');
```